# Can I set up one Parallels VM to start automatically while leaving the rest off?

Tags: parallels-desktop

I set up a Windows 7 VM using parallels (uses boot camp partition - wow its very fast), and another VM running WinXP (for legacy stuff).

What I need is to automatically fire up that Windows 7 VM when I log into MacOS, but NOT run the WinXP VM.

I see I can right-click on Parallels icon and choose Options > Open at Login, but I am thinking that will either (1) not actually start up my Win7 machine or (2) will run both of them - neither is my desired result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Under the account settings, there is a list of items that run on start up, per user.

Place a shortcut to the Windows 7 VM in there, that should do the trick.

Comment: Perfect - exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

If you let Parallels close with Windows open (or running), presumably using Mac's open as left function, it'll re-open on reboot in the same state?

Comment: i'll try it  and let you know if it works :)